# Can't get basic file input to work! (fstream)

Tags: c++, fstream

Why won't my program open my .txt document? The document is at the specified location. And I know that \i is not an **Escape Sequence**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream fin("C:\\input.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cerr << "Error, couldn't open txt file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alternatively use this code to input any file that is stored at    ***C:\\text.txt*** into console window.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

 ifstream myReadFile;
 myReadFile.open("D:\\text.txt");
 char output[100];
 if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
    while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
        myReadFile >> output;
        cout << output;
    }
}

myReadFile.close();
return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The document is at the specified location.

It's at `C:\\input.txt`? Really?

I'm pretty sure you intended:

```
fstream fin("C:\\input.txt");
```

That `\\` is an escape sequence, resulting in a single backslash…

…and, ultimately, the path `C:\input.txt`.

Comment: inb4: Yes, this _is_ an answer.

Comment: Yes, for simplicity's sake